# How to check if PowerShell pipeline returns true for each pipeline element?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I would like to compare objects and return true if they match. In the end, the pipeline should only return a single boolean - true if each pipeline element returned true and false otherwise. How can I achieve this with only using the Pipeline?

Example:

```
@("a","b","c") | % { $_ -match "[a-z]" } # -> should only return true once
@("a","1","c") | % { $_ -match "[a-z]" } # -> should only return false once
```

Comment: You could also use `-notcontains` for this: `(@("a","b","c") | % { $_ -match "[a-z]" }) -notcontains $false` returns `True`. That's not using the pipeline though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use a single pipeline instead of multiple statements, you can probably do something like that:

```
$data | % { check } | sort -unique | select -first 1
```

This will check every element, sort the results and remove duplicates, so the only outcomes at this point are `$false`, `$false,$true`, and `$true`. We then take only the first value. That one is only `$true` if every element passed the check.

If you're not that adverse to other statements or expressions around the pipeline, you can do a collection count check, or invert the condition and then negate the result:

```
!($data | ? { !(check) })
```

The pipeline will either return `$null`, or a number of items. The boolean **not** will then coerce that to a boolean value. The only problem with this approach is when only one item matches the inverted check and it's equivalent to `$false` (e.g. an empty string, or `0`).

Answer (score 4):

If you have PowerShell 4, you can use Linq with

```
$data = ("a","b","c")
$testFunction = [func[object,bool]] {param($item) $item -match "[a-z]"}

[Linq.Enumerable]::All($data, $testFunction)
```

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. Didn't know about Linq until now.

Comment: I constantly keep forgetting it, especially since it's not as nice to use as a pipeline from PowerShell and does mostly the same things. I think a nice addition would be a `-All` parameter on `Where-Object`, and maybe `-None`, although that'd implicitly reverse the meaning of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses `Where-Object` (alias: `? { ... }`) to:

- remove collection iterates that do not match your condition.
- compare the count of the resulting collection to the count of the original collection. If none were removed (if all match your condition), the statement returns true.

**Code:**

```
PS C:\> $arr = @("a","b","c")
PS C:\> @($arr | ? { $_ -match "[a-z]" }).Count -eq @($arr).Count
True

PS C:\> $arr = @("a","1","c")
PS C:\> @($arr | ? { $_ -match "[a-z]" }).Count -eq @($arr).Count
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the other answers I came up with another solution which also only returns true or false

```
@("a","b","c") | % { $_ -match "[a-z]" } | Measure-Object -Sum | % { $_.Count -eq $_.sum }
@("a","1","c") | % { $_ -match "[a-z]" } | Measure-Object -Sum | % { $_.Count -eq $_.sum }
```